# Dynamically set click event on bar from highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, highcharts

I want to have a hyperlink to a different page when clicking on a bar from the highcharts graph.

Something like this:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        window.location.href = '/result/question/questionid/';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

But my problem is I want to set this dynamically. I have a function createChart() where I form the highcharts.

So I have variable where I form all the options of the highchart. But now I want to set the location with a variable that I get when the function is called (is always different). Does someone knows how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.. how do get that variable? You can use something like this:

```
click: function() {
    redirect();
}
```

And then define somewhere in your code:

```
function redirect() {
    window.location.href = myVariable;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code:

```
var urlContainer ="";
```

update the variable above whenever you need, then in your highcharts click callback, do something like:

```
 plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                     window.location.href = urlContainer;
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```